# Workflow Current Item Boolean does not work

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I'm wondering if anyone has run into this situation.

I have a 2010 workflow running on a SharePoint 2013 hosted site.

I am checking for a boolean field in the workflow. The boolean is set correctly in the list as true and my log statement does in fact show the field is set to true. There are no errors in the log.

The code below my IF statement should fire but it never does. What could cause this not to work?

**If current item:Resubmit equals yes**

Thanks!

Comment: "Resubmit equals yes" - So simple, but have you tried: Resubmit == true to evaluate this?

Comment: are you sure if Statement is being hit? And i guess its a typo from your end as "Y" should be capital.

Comment: @Taran Thanks for replying. I believe the IF is being hit. I have a log right before the IF which tells me the value of "Resubmit". Correct on the typo. That should be "Yes".

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm using SharePoint Designer to script these workflows. I cannot set anything outside of the values the drop down displays. Since the field is boolean, I can only select Yes or No. The same goes for the "equals". (I can select only "equals" or "not equals") . I believe the IF should be hit as I have a log right before it telling me the value of Resubmit ("true"). It just seems to always evaluate to false.

Comment: Is it a Yes/No type field created OOTB? You are using it as checkbox or drop down? I am trying to replicate.

Comment: It is a check box on the form. That part works fine. Is there any sort of permission that has to be set? The service that runs the workflow was created by a different user. This workflow was created by me so can the permissions be off?

Comment: Even I faced the same issue. I ended up assigning it to a workflow variable and using that variable in the condition. This could be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I have a very long 2010 SPD workflow with tons of Boolean IF logic.
The workflow worked beautifully as I was developing it, but at some point the Boolean logic stopped behaving correctly. I have no idea why.

MY SOLUTION
I changed my If statements to test for the opposite condition and they all worked.
So, for example if I wanted to test if a SharePoint List Yes/No variable was "Yes":

INSTEAD OF - If Current Item:YourColumn equals Yes

I USE      - If Current Item:YourColumn not equals No

Everything now works as long as I can keep my head on straight as I work my way through the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Assigning the field value to a variable, then using the variable in the "if" condition, worked for me.
(Solution suggested in the comments)