# SharePoint Workflow condition fails to evaluate to true even with true condition

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

Currently running SharePoint 2010 in a emulation mode on SharePoint 2013. I have a workflow with two Boolean variables, let's just call them x and y for simplicity, which are set to yes or no based on the evaluation of prior steps.

The problem is I have a condition to check for the combination when x is true AND y is false but when these values of x and y match that condition the workflow doesn't seem to evaluate it properly and thus the nested steps in that condition never run.
There was a similar question asked in this site but without any resolution. I've provided a link to that here [prior inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254741/workflow-current-item-boolean-does-not-work)

What I would like to know is there anyone who can shed some light on this issue?

I have placed a log and tracer variables to record and tell me what internal values are leading up to the conditional and these prove to be what is expected.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please send screen shots. Do not use else statement. Use separate if statements.